# Fairness & starvation in processing with Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My users can upload any number of files during any time of the day with say 10000 records in each file. The individual records are published to 5 partitions P1,P2,P3,P4,P5 for processing. I have 5 consumers in the group which will consume from those 5 partitions and process the records.

So when the user uploads file F1, 2500 records will be queued in P1, 2500 in P2 and so on.

While this processing is going on, another user uploads file F2. But records in F2 wont get processed by the consumers until the records of F1 are processed (FIFO).

How do I ensure fairness in Kafka processing. That is, records in F2 should also be processed rather than waiting for records in F1 to be completed from the queue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Producing side, nothing special to do to be fair. 
If you have a KafkaProducer instance per file, you will ensure producing fairness.

Let's say you have your File F1 processing thread T1 with a KafkaProducer Kp1.
T1 will start reading records from F1 and produce records with Kp1.
Let's say T1 it reached the record 100 'R100'
Kp1 produced R100..

Then, at this moment, you instantiate T2 that will handle another file F2 with its own records.
T2 will read R1 and Kp2 will produce R1' as well.

So will end up with two streams of file records interlaced, thus consumed with fairness.

Kp1 produced R101.. 
Kp2 produced R2'... 
Kp1 produced R102... 
Kp2 produced R3'...
Etc..

Consuming side, it depends on how your file records are being produced. If your 10000 records take 1 second to produce but 1 minute to consume/process, and you expect maximum 5 files per minute , then you can envisage to have a file dedicated per partition ( using key), but you'll still be not fair in case the key hash is the same for two consecutive files... ( not fair 100 % of the time).

Kafka is not the best solution to avoid starvation. It's not a queue techno like rabbitMQ would be.

You'll end up with a consumer dedicated per partition at the best, but you cannot be sure that your files will be evenly spread amongs the partitions ( except if you develop kind of watcher that look for free partition before assigning a partititon to a record)..

Yannick

Comment: Dedicating a file per partition with key hash might be a short term solution, but then not scalable as I have to increase partitions on the fly to support more files. You are right, Kafka is not the solution for this.